# A variable is in the scope of only some of thees python nested function definitions but not all, why?

Tags: python, scope

In the code below:

```
def f():
    a = 'x'

    def g():
        print(a)
        if a == 'x':
            return True
        return False

    def h():
        print(a)
        def i():
            a = a + a
            return a

        a = i()

        return a

    if g():
        return h()
```

Why is `a` accessible in function `g`, but not in function `h` or `i`?

I don't want to use `nonlocal` since I don't want to modify `a` in any of the inner functions, however I don't see why `a` itself is not accessible.

Comment: Because you assign in `h` and `i`.

Comment: "I don't want to use nonlocal since I don't want to modify a in any of the inner functions" - if you don't want to modify `a` in the inner functions, *why are they assigning to `a`*?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: But does it matter that it is accessed prior to `a` being assigned?

Comment: @user2357112: I want a local copy of `a` to be modified, so that `a` itself is remained intact if any other nested functions are there as well.

Comment: @Atonal: no. Python does *not* inspect the code paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: because you **assigned to `a`** (by writing `a = a + a` and `a = i()`), you **created local variables**. The fact that you **use variables before assignment does not matter**.

Python checks the scope by **checking assignments**. If you somewhere write an assignment like `a =`, `a +=`, etc. **regardless where you write it in the function**, the function sees `a` as a local scope variable.

So in case you write:

```
a = 2

def f():
    print(a)
    a = 3
```

Even if you **access `a` before you assign to `a`**, it will still see `a` as a local variable. Python does not do codepath analysis here.

it sees `a` a a local variable in `f`. It will error if you call `f()`, since it will say you fetch `a` before it is actually assigned.

In case a variable is *not* defined locally, Python will iteratively inspect the outer scopes until it finds an `a`.

The only ways to access a variable from an outer scope if you assign to in a scope is by working with `nonlocal` or `global` (or of course passing it as a parameter).

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept you're answer in "9 minutes"! However I have to ask: 1) why does python do this? 2) what do I need to do to have a local copy of `a`  inside the inner function and modify it?

Comment: @Atonal: if you write a `for` loop, and you assign to a variable `a`, you can later use that variable. But a compiler would argue: "*there is no proof that the body of the `for` loop will be executed, so there is no guarantee that `a` is assigned.*". Python is a rather dynamic language. codepath analysis can create trouble here.

Answer (score 1):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45579117/1405065) is great for explaining what's going wrong. I'm adding my own answer to try to explain some of the reasons behind the issue (i.e. the "why" rather the "what").

First you need to understand Python's architecture a little bit. We often describe Python as an "interpreted" language rather than a "compiled" language like C, but that's not really the whole story. While Python doesn't compile directly to machine code, the interpreter doesn't run on the raw source code when the program is running. Rather, there's an intermediate step where the source code is compiled to to bytecode. The compiling happens automatically when a module is loaded, so you may not even be aware of it (though you may have seen the `.pyc` files that the compiler writes to cache the bytecode).

Anyway, to get back to your scope issue: Python's compiler uses a bytecode instruction to tell the interpreter to access a local variable rather than it uses for accessing a global variable (and third different instruction is sued for to accessing a variable from an enclosing function's scope). Since the bytecode is written by the compiler, the bytecode instruction to use needs to be decided at a function's compile time, not when the function is called. The choice of instruction is tricky though for ambiguous code like this:

```
a = 1

def foo():
    if bar():
        a = 2
    print(a)
```

Does the access of `a` for the `print` call use the bytecode instruction that reads the global variable `a` or the instruction that accesses the local variable `a`? There's no way for the compiler to know in advance if `bar` will return a true value or not, so there's no possible answer that will let the function work in all situations.

To avoid ambiguity, Python's designers chose that the scope of a variable should be constant throughout each function (so the compiler can just pick one bytecode instruction and stick with it). That is, a name like `a` can refer to local or a global (or a closure cell) but only one of those in any given function.

The compiler defaults to using local variables (which are the fastest to access) for any name used as the target of an assignment anywhere in the function's code. Since inner functions are compiled at the same time as the functions that contain them, non-local lookups can also be detected at compile time and the appropriate instruction used. If the name isn't found in either the local or the enclosing scopes, the compiler assumes it is a global variable (which doesn't need to be defined yet). The `global` and `nonlocal` statements allow you to explicitly tell the compiler to use a specific scope (overriding what it would pick on its own).

You can explore the different ways the compiler handles variable lookups in different scopes using the `dis` module from the standard library. The `dis` module disassembles bytecode into a more readable format. Try calling `dis.dis` on functions like these:

```
a = 1

def load_global():
    print(a) # access the global variable "a"

def load_fast():
    a = 2
    print(a) # access the local variable "a", which shadows the global variable

def closure():
    a = 2
    def load_dref():
        print(a) # access the variable "a" from the enclosing scope
    return load_dref

load_dref = closure() # both dis.dis(closure) and dis.dis(load_dref) are interesting
```

The full details of how to interpret the output of `dis.dis` are beyond the scope (no pun intended) of this answer, but the main things to look for are the `LOAD_...` bytecode instructions that deal with `(a)` as their target. You'll see three different `LOAD_...` instructions in the different functions above, corresponding to the three different kinds of scopes they're reading from (each function is named for the corresponding instruction).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! I have to ask though, since you said "There's no way for the compiler to know in advance ... in all situations." then can I infer that either AST is not involved in the compilation step as much as a lisp, or the compilation step is this way due to ease of implementation, or the namespace is unordered like a dictionary (since you have `ctx.load` in the AST but not `ctx.save`, so it has to be impossible to move  down the stack looking for it hence unorderedness)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. The issue is at a lower level than the AST. In the ASTs for all the functions above, the `a` lookup is the same (a `Name(id='a')` node). However, the compiler needs to emit a more specific bytecode instruction to load the variable. Which instruction depends on which scope it's loading the variable from, and that can't handle any ambiguity. I suppose Python's interpreter could allow a failed local variable lookup to fall through to a non-local or global variable, but I suspect that would have been slower and (more importantly) more confusing.